# Why compiler cannot figure out that constructors are in fact constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Consider [this code](https://godbolt.org/g/cnnMUr):

```
struct matrix
{
    matrix(int a, int b, int c, int d)
        : a(a), b(b), c(c), d(d){}
    matrix()
        : a(0), b(0), c(0), d(0){}
    int a, b, c, d;
};

static const matrix mx0;
static const matrix mx1(1,1,1,1);

const matrix& test(bool f)
{
    return f ? mx1 : mx0;
}
```

Why can't compiler figure out and avoid generating all that messy code to init these two global statics `mx0` and `mx1`?

Why only when I [mark constructors constexpr](https://godbolt.org/g/ojpf8L), compiler is able to do what I would expect it to do without this keyword? Note, with optimizations enabled compiler sill [doesn't generate the same result](https://godbolt.org/g/DVBaP1) as with [code that uses constexpr](https://godbolt.org/g/b3RP3o).

Comment: Try optimizations. Optmizations tell the compiler to figure stuff out that you don't tell it.

Comment: @KerrekSB True, I forgot to add `-O2`, still, constexpr produces considerably better results.

Comment: Without `constexpr`, the initializations are performed at runtime, not at compile-time.  Things initialized at compile-time are more compact since the compiler works out the final result and then generates code for only that.

Comment: Or [switch to a better compiler](https://godbolt.org/g/MpXC6E)?

Comment: @KerrekSB oh, yes, much better result. The problem however, is that non-optimized builds might have global initialization issues.

Comment: @Pavel: And the language allows you to avoid those issues portably: with `constexpr`

Comment: So, the compiler *can* figure things out, but it *doesn't* generally, because the language rules don't require it. People wanted this thing to be available deterministically, so the language got a new rule that lets you express this, and the compiler has to play by that rule. I'm not sure what else you want.

Comment: Are you complaining that your compiler doesn't do good optimizations? Move to a different compiler and request your money back for the one you bought.

Comment: @SergeyA I'm not complaining, I'm asking why it cannot or does not do the same optimizations. In any case, the issue is still there with non-optimized debug builds. But as @KerrekSB noted "language allows you to avoid those issues portably: with `constexpr`"

Comment: I am still unsure what you are asking. Why it can't optimize those initializations? Because nobody programmed it to do it. What else can we tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off let me say this is a guess, but (I believe) it's an educated one.

I'm not on the C++ standards committee, but from what I have read and seen online I can tell you that they were (and still are) very hot on backwards compatibility with previous versions of the language.  If C++11 compilers were to be allowed to silently apply `constexpr` to constructors and initialisation of const variables then that would change the behaviour of existing programs when recompiled under C++11 - moving from run-time to compile-time initialisation.  In general, changing the behaviour of programs when simply recompiling in a later version of the language is seen to be a bad thing*.

Therefore, to obtain new behaviour that was not previously possible under you are required to change the original code to something that would not previously have been legal C++.  Requiring the new `constexpr` keyword to be on the constructor (or other function) declaration is a simple, effective way to do this.

---

*<sub>Of course, there are exceptions to every rule, such as compiler generated move constructors/assignment operators, but they were very careful that these could not be automatically added except where provably benign.</sub>

Comment: That's what I felt was the reason, but was curious if there is something in the standard that prevents compiler from applying these optimizations, or if such optimizations would break some rules or requirements

Comment: My answer refers to the standard and not compilers.  Basically, compilers don't do it because the standard says not to; and the standard says not to because it has the potential to break existing code.